# by Lazy: не срабатывает инициализация

Tags: android, kotlin, lazyloading, livedata

Есть вот такой код с `byLazy` и `LiveData`.
И он крашится. Говорит что `"listMyTrades.value == null"`

```
 val emptyDepositListBean: DepositListBean by lazy {
        val dbl = DepositListBean()
        dbl.deposits = mutableListOf()
        dbl
    }

var listMyTrades = MutableLiveData<DepositListBean>().apply { value = emptyDepositListBean }
```

Если заменить `byLazy` на `apply`, то все будет работать корректно:

```
val emptyDepositListBean: DepositListBean = DepositListBean().apply { deposits = mutableListOf() }

var listMyTrades = MutableLiveData<DepositListBean>().apply { value = emptyDepositListBean }
```

Сообственно вопрос: разве так должно быть?
разве строчка `value = emptyDepositListBean` не должна заставять проводить `Lazy` инициализацию, а затем помещаться в `LiveData` ?

Comment: Попробуйте сделать `listMyTrades` тоже `by lazy`. Он сейчас инициализируется в момент создания объекта, там могут быть тонкости с инициализацией используемых ленивых свойств

Comment: а зачем вам lazy, если вы сразу же используете эту проперти? плюс у MutableLiveData есть конструктор, в который можно передать начальное значение, так что apply не нужен `MutableLiveData(emptyDepositListBean)`

Comment: @IR42 вопрос не про "как сделать", а "почему lazy себя так ведет". просто для меня, такое поведение неочевидное. вот и хочу разобраться в том, как работает byLazy

Comment: Вообще в приведённом коде всё нормально, может добавите хотя бы код где у вас крашится? У вас точно listMyTrades находится ниже emptyDepositListBean? Какая версия котлина?

Comment: @IR42 точно ниже. Котлин 1.5.20. Краш происходит когда слушатель LiveData лезет в value и не находит там инициализированного массива. т.е. listMyTrades.value == null

Comment: Код Ок, должен работать. Но как уже сказано, использование lazy здесь абсолютно избыточно. Возможно такой вариант в JetBrains просто не покрыт тестом, вот баг и проскочил.